# About Network sockets and programming

Tags: network-programming

I can't imagine the creating network packet from top-layer of TCP/IP to lowest-layer on network programming. I have an idea about this process but don't know is it true.

In the application layer when we want to establish our program on network, we use the libraries or modules about networking in programming language that we work on it. But I heard the Operating Systems have their own implemented protocol stack software like Berkeley Sockets etc. I can't seperate these things from each other.

How these modules/libraries/stacks works from beginning the creation of packet?

Is network libraries/modules of programming language just making a system call to operating system? And the implemented network stack in Operating System kernel does the all thing about packet?

Thanks for all answers.